# Segmentation Fault with C++ class network programming

Tags: c++, class, networking, pthreads, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a c++ program that uses classes, starts and listens for network connections, and then spins off a new thread for each new client.

Fortunately, I've figured out how to spawn a thread from inside a class, but when trying to do a accept() in the class I get a segmentation fault. I'll post the code to make it a little easier to show where I'm having issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h> //for memset
#include <pthread>
#include <sys/types.h> //network
#include <sys/socket.h> //network
#include <netinet/in.h> //network

using namespace std;
class network
{
  public:
    void my_listen();
    static void *handleClient(void * in_stream);
};

void* network::handleClient(void * in_stream)
{

  int *stream = reinterpret_cast<int *>(in_stream);
  write(*stream,"Hello Client\n", 12);
}

void network::my_listen()
{
  /*
   * Name: my_listen()
   * Purpose: Listens and accepts new connections. Once accpeted, a new thread
   *          is spun off. 
   * Input: none
   * Output: none
  */

  int *new_socket_desc;
  int port_num = 9876;
  socklen_t client_addr_len;

  int socket_desc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

  sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

  if(socket_desc == -1)
  {
    cerr << "Unable to create new sockets\n";
  }

  memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port_num);

  if(bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
  {
    cerr << "Error on binding " << port_num << endl;
  }

  listen(socket_desc,5);

  client_addr_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  pthread_t thread[10];
  int count = 0;

  *new_socket_desc = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &client_addr_len); //Right here I segment fault

  cout << "Connected client " << " @ " << new_socket_desc << " (" << *new_socket_desc << ")" <<  endl;

  pthread_create(thread[0], handleClient, (void *)new_socket_desc);

  pthread_join(thread[0],NULL);
}
```

Main isn't that exciting:

```
#include "network.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  network my_network;

  my_network.my_listen();
}
```

What is interesting is that I can get all of this to work without using a class. I'm sure it has something to do with scope, but I don't know why.

By the way, I'm using gcc 4.6.2 with a target platform of x86_64

Comment: It's not C++. It's fugly C/C++.

Comment: BTW, if this is homework, please tag as such.

Comment: @antlersoft: [NO!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I will say it is nasty bastardized C\C++ code that is begging to be put out of it's misery; however, I think it's readable and it does serve it's purpose. Is there a more C++ way to write this though? I thought pthreads didn't have a C++ interface.

Comment: @SailorCire Why would you want to use pthreads, when you have `std::thread`?!

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I've never heard of it until now (thanks!). Is there anything particularly 'wrong' with pthreads, besides the code looks funny?     Personal note: it looks like I should update gcc as it's gives me a nice warning to make sure I include -std=gnu++0x when using `std::thread`

Comment: @SailorCire Well, usually keeping your compiler up-to-date is a good idea. And just to clarify : `-std=c++11`. It's official now. (If 4.6.2 won't accept it yet, c++0x or gnu0x is ok)

Comment: @antlersoft This is academic, but I was not given a homework assignment that was "Write a C++ program that uses TCP, classes, and threads" or something like that. That would be cheating, and I would frown upon myself for that.

Comment: For future use: I just made everything local for simplicity of the problem. In reality, I'll pass a struct pointer, copy everything over to the thread's stack, and then do what I need to do. Using a struct is better, because I can pass and use multiple values instead just one int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare new_socket_desc as a pointer but never set what it is pointing to.  When you try to put a value at the location of the pointer (with the result of your accept call) it is writing to some random location in memory, which may or may not cause an immediate crash (in this version of your code it is causing a crash) but is always very bad.

Make new_socket_desc a regular int member of your class, use the & operator on it when creating the thread, and don't use the * operator on it otherwise, and you should have better luck.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. Although you said this, I'm rewording it in case someone else has a similar issue. When you declare int *pointer, you are naming and reserving a space in memory, so pointer is just a memory address and is **meant to hold _another_ memory address**. When I made an assignment with *pointer = 5; I am writing 5 to that memory location (which appears to be what I want), but that 5 isn't referring to the value 5, it's referring to the memory location 0x5.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *new_socket_desc;
// ....
*new_socket_desc = accept(socket_desc ....
```

You declaring new_socket_desc as a unitialized pointer, then assigning result of `accept` to random memory location pointed by `new_socket_desc`. So obviously this causes SEGFAULT. You should do:

```
int new_socket_desc;
// ....
new_socket_desc = accept(socket_desc ....
```